# Php ajax Poll system with multiple answer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make a poll system using php, mysql and ajax. I have created poll table from database.

```
id
answer
vote
```

I want users to increase their answers and i have created a simple javascript function like this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/eWVzVO)**

```
<div class="inputsl">
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createPoll" name="mypoll" class="myinput"></div>
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createPoll" name="mypoll" class="myinput"></div>
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createPoll" name="mypoll" class="myinput"></div>
   <div class="inputt"><input type="text" id="createPoll" name="mypoll" class="myinput"></div>
</div>
```

I have also created ajax function for inserting answers

```
$("body").on("click",".insertp", function(){
       var poll = $("#createPoll").val();
       var dataPoll = 'poll=' + poll;
       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/requests/postPoll',
           data: dataPoll,
           cache: false,
           beforeSend: function(){},
           sucess: function(){
               console.log("Success!");
           }   
        });
     });
```

and the postPoll.php functions

```
<?php 
include_once '../inc/inc.php';
if(isset($_POST['poll'])){
    $poll = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['poll']);
    if($poll){
foreach($poll as  $setPoll){
      $insertPollfromData = $InSert->Insert_Poll($uid, $setPoll);
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Now, i want to insert multiple answer from poll table but my postPoll.php gives me this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

How can i insert multiple poll from database ? Anyone can help me here ?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: you only use `foreach` when iterating over `arrays`. seems `$poll` is not an array but a boolean. Also where does `$uid` come from?

Comment: @Akin.. i m agree with u..

Comment: To accomplish your task, you'll probably need to set the input field where the user enters answers to `array` e.g `create_answer[]` and then iterate on your php side

Answer (score 1):

In your html i would u suggest using a `<form>` and append inputs to it. then you can use https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

To send the serialized data from all the inputs to your PHP file trough ajax.